# How to connect div and javascript functions and event and create function that proceed value from drop down list to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a drop-down list with car names. I want to create an event in javascript which after selecting some elements from the drop down list will be passed to the div block using that function. For example, I select an Audi from my drop-down list and in the div block to print it is an Audi. I want to create an event and a function that, after selecting one of the options from the drop-down list with that function, will be passed to the giant block. I've created a function that takes the value of an item from a drop-down list but I just don't know how to proceed to my goal
Here is my code

```js
function jsFunction(value) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
  var newparagraph = document.createElement("p");
  newparagraph.innerText(value);
  div1.appendChild(newparagraph);
}
```

```html
<select id="ddl" name="ddl" onmousedown="this.html='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
  <option id="Audi1" value='1'>Audi</option>
  <option id="Mercedes2" value='2'>Mercedes</option>
  <option id="BMW3" value='3'>BMW</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Comment: Typo `newparagraph.innerText = value;` - I would use textContent instead

Comment: Also use a "please select" otherwise the user cannot accedd Audi without flipping back and forth

Comment: I change that but still my code does not work

Comment: Yes it does. It shows the value which is 1, 2 or 3. And options do not need IDs

Comment: But how can I make when I choose Audi from my drop down list that div block get text where write "You choose Audi". I do not know how to connect that with function and make javascript function for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newparagraph.innerText = value;` will show 1, 2 or 3

You need the text of the options

note I wrrap the code in a load event handler so we can place the code where we want including in the head

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("ddl").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (!this.value) return
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
    var newparagraph = document.createElement("p");
    newparagraph.textContent = 'You chose ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    div1.appendChild(newparagraph);
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="ddl" name="ddl">
  <option value=''>Please select</option>
  <option value='1'>Audi</option>
  <option value='2'>Mercedes</option>
  <option value='3'>BMW</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Comment: One also could use `this.selectedOptions[0].text` instead of `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: Hmm it is weird. This code works in code snippet but it does not work in google chrome. Here is code from my visual studio code again

Comment: @PeterSeliger That is one I never saw before. It is not compatible with older browser by the way

Comment: I will post screenshoot

Comment: @Edoprog I wrrapped it in a load. If your code is pasted before the element exists

Comment: Thanks everybody I solved my problem